# 'Roster_Name = Roster_List[1] IndexError: list index out of range", list "Roster_List" has 3 elements? - Python

Tags: python

One of my assignments requires that if a user inputs "add Jim 100" or something similar, that the code splits each word and number into a list, which is then inputted into a separate dictionary. This code chunk works in my IDE(Eclipse), however on the website (Stepik.com) where I submit the code, I get the error:

```
    Roster_Name = Roster_List[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am confused as to why the error appears because Roster_List has 3 elements assuming the user inputs the string correctly and I think I called the elements properly. i.e. "add Jim 100" = ["add", "Jim", 100]. I am confused even more because the code recognizes "Roster_Command = Roster_List[0] just fine.

Can anybody explain why I am wrong or why the error appears?

```
exit = "no"
Roster_Complete = {}
Roster_Command = ""
Roster_Name = ""
Roster_Score = ""
while exit == "no":
    Roster_input = input()
    Roster_List = Roster_input.split(" ")
    print(Roster_List)
    Roster_Command = Roster_List[0]
    if Roster_Command == "print":
        pass
    else:
        Roster_Name = Roster_List[1]
        Roster_Score = int(Roster_List[2])
    if(Roster_Command == "add"):
        if Roster_Score > 100:
            print("Failed to add", Roster_Name)
        else:
            Roster_Complete.update({Roster_Name:Roster_Score})
            print("Added", Roster_Name)
    elif Roster_Command == "update":
        if Roster_Name in Roster_Complete:
            Roster_Complete[Roster_Name] = Roster_Score
            print("Updated" , Roster_Name + "'s grade")
        else:
            print(Roster_Name,"Does not exist in the roster")
    elif Roster_Command == "print":
        for x,y in Roster_Complete.items():
            print(x + ":", y)
    elif Roster_Command == "exit":
        exit = "exit"
```

The reason I set the elements to variables is because of syntax in other parts of the code.

Edit: This is what the website enters as the pre-defined inputs:

```
add narges 0
print
exit
```

Thanks!

Comment: See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: Your key problem is "assuming the user inputs the string correctly".   It appears that there is no element `1` in the list.  You haven't provided the actual input or the full error message (although there *should* be only one possible reference).

Comment: The website has pre-defined inputs it enters when you execute/test the code, thus no inputs are strictly added by me.

Comment: Your first example was closer to a MRE, except that you *still* haven't provided the critical input data.

Comment: Also, you have print(Roster_List). Does this show up? Do you see a three element list?

Comment: Yes Roster_List prints fine in my IDE. Thats why I am confused as to why the error appears on the Website. I put the print statement there strictly to see if the list is being properly formed

Answer (score 0):

The input ‘exit’ triggers the error. ‘exit’ is not ‘print’, but it seems your code goes on to expect more elements.

Perhaps this line:

```
if(Roster_Command == "add"):
```

should be moved up to replace the ‘else:’ above it.

Comment: Got it I found the error. I just set  the if Roster_Command == "print": to if Roster_Command == "print" or "Roster_Command == "exit":

Comment: Good catch!. Nick, try moving your line     __elif Roster_Command == "exit":
        exit = "exit"__ to just after your input statement (changing your elif to if).